# Visual Studio Mac 2022 doesn't find my added folder and files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor

I am switched from a windows laptop to a macbook and now my Blazor project won't work anymore, because I'm facing error co0246

> The type or namespace name 'Model' does not exist in the namespace 'HiddenVillaTest' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234) (HiddenVillaTest)

When I create a new Blazor project everything works from scratch until I add a folder or copy and paste folders and files.

I don't know what to do now.

I tried several ways to fix this problem but non of them worked.

- 1. I copied the folder within files in the project folder on my mac.
- 2. I added a new folder in the HiddenVillaTest Project and added two c#-classes, where I copied all the sorcecode inside.
- 3. I restarted visual studio a couple times and restarted my mac.
- 4. @using with and without the Projectname infront of the folder -> HiddenVillaTest.Model

non of this work and I have no idea why. I researched on Google for a coulpe hours but wasn't  found anything helpful.

On my mac is installed .Net Core 3.1 and .Net 6.0. Do I miss anything?

Screenshot of the issue:

You can see that I try to add a reference to my model folder, but Visual Studio cannot see ot find the folder.

[image]

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. As always, the issue sits 40 cm in front of the monitor…

Because I copied and pasted the folders from a different named project, I forgot to rename the namespace inside booth files.

Problem:
[wrong namespace name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhBF0.png)

fix:
[right namespace name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBmxX.png)

After fixing this, everything runs perfect.